# Determining the "optimal" common numeric type in a template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

What is the best way to determine a **common** numeric type in a template parameter pack with:

1. the smallest size,
2. no loss of precision, and
3. no risk of overflow/underflow when converting any type in the parameter pack to this "ideal" common type?

The variadic template (`best_common_numeric_type`) could be used like so:

```
template<typename... NumericTypes>
auto some_numeric_func(const NumericTypes&...)
-> typename best_common_numeric_type<NumericTypes...>::type;
```

And have instantiations like the following:

```
[1] best_common_numeric_type<long, unsigned long, float, double, int>::type = double
[2] best_common_numeric_type<unsigned int, unsigned long>::type = unsigned long
[3] best_common_numeric_type<signed int, signed long>::type = signed long
[4] best_common_numeric_type<signed int, unsigned int>::type = signed long
[5] best_common_numeric_type<signed int, unsigned long>::type = int128_t (maybe)
```

So in case [4] for example, `::type` would have to be `signed long`, since `signed int` could not hold an `unsigned int` without risk of overflow, and conversely `unsigned int` could not hold a `signed int` without risk of underflow.

The same applies in [5], except now a `signed long` is no longer sufficient since it could not hold the `unsigned long` without risk of overflow.

(The implementation might be [data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) specific, but you get the idea.)

So what might be the best way in C++11 to achieve this?

Comment: What's wrong with [std::common_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)?

Comment: @DanielKO: I tried `std::common_type` for all 5 cases, and it worked for 1-3 because they are very simple cases, but "returned" `unsigned int` for case [4] (instead of `signed long`) and `unsigned long` for case [5] (instead of a signed integer type wider than `long`). This is because those types *can* be converted to the unsigned counterparts, but not without potential underflow which must be avoided for `best_common_numeric_type`.

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish with this? Trying to perform a binary operation with two arguments? What if the result of the operation overflows?

Comment: what about `<signed long long, unsigned long long>`?  Some combinations have no results.  Also `<long long, double>`.  (Also note that `long` is 32 bits on some systems, so #4 might be wrong)

Comment: @DanielKO: The *result* of a binary operation can *always* overflow (or underflow for signed types or subtraction) regardless of the operand types. This template is just to get a common type in which all types can be converted to while meeting the optimal critiera stated in the question, some of which `std::common_type` doesn't satisfy as explained in the previous comment.

Comment: @MooningDuck: Correct. In those cases, the template can only deduce the "best" type possible (and might generate a warning or static_assert failure, which are details that **can** be ignored for the sake of answering this question). To your second point, I noted in the question that the implementation might be "data model" specific, but that can also be ignored (i.e., a data model can be assumed). A data-model-agnostic solution might be to use templates like `signed_int_with_size_gt<...>::type` etc., but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @MikeTusar: I can't come up with a way that doesn't involve specializing a class for all 289 pairs of two types...

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, it is also a variadic template (accepts any number of types, not just two). The idea I had was to check if any types were floating point, then return the highest-precision floating point if so. Otherwise (all integral), check if any types are signed, then get "max sizeof", plus some other meta-programming techniques to avoid specializing for all the types, which would be impossible anyway for a variadic template (combinatorial explosion).

Comment: @MooingDuck: But thanks for investigating anyway. I asked this question hoping someone knew of something (e.g., in boost) or had already done something similar and would share, as I could not find anything through a Google search (and `std::common_type` isn't perfectly suited for it).

Comment: @MikeTusar: I just thought of that after I posted.  What you just listed is actually quite easy.

Comment: @MikeTusar: IF you can solve it for two, it's trivial to extend that to solve for any number.

Comment: Your examples #1 and #4 are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: If I understand your comment correctly, you're saying that a solution cannot satisfy both cases (1 and 4)? see the solution posted by leonid-volnitsky as it satisifies all criteria and cases stated in the question (and quite elegantly, less than 20 lines of code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a little bit late to the party, 
here is my solution without Boost:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
  
template<class I, bool Signed> struct mk_signed { typedef I       type; };
template<>   struct mk_signed<uint8_t , true>   { typedef int16_t type; };
template<>   struct mk_signed<uint16_t, true>   { typedef int32_t type; };
template<>   struct mk_signed<uint32_t, true>   { typedef int64_t type; };
template<>   struct mk_signed<uint64_t, true>   { typedef int64_t type; }; 
  
template <typename... Ts> struct best_common_numeric_type;
template <typename T>     struct best_common_numeric_type<T> { typedef T type; };
  
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct best_common_numeric_type<T, Ts...> {
   typedef typename best_common_numeric_type<Ts...>::type TS;     
   typedef typename std::conditional < (sizeof(T) > sizeof(TS)), T, TS>::type  bigger_integral;
   constexpr static bool fp = std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_floating_point<TS>::value;
   constexpr static bool have_signed = !fp && (std::is_signed<T>::value || std::is_signed<TS>::value);
  
   typedef typename std::conditional <
     fp,
     typename std::common_type<T,TS>::type,
     typename mk_signed<bigger_integral,have_signed>::type
   >::type type;
};
```

Comment: I like it. +1 I was hoping you'd complete/resurrect that answer

Comment: @sehe: I agree, this solution seems about as simple and clean as possible. I think because this is a *complete* solution (handles floating point), is quite a bit simpler, and uses only standard libraries, I think it deserves to be the accepted ("best") answer. I wish SO allowed accepting two answers, because yours is also outstanding and very interesting as a more MPL-based solution.

Comment: Outstanding. And surprisingly simple.

Answer (score 6):

You could use Boost Integer to select the proper cases.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html#boost_integer.integer.sized

Ignoring for a moment the cases on non-integral element types, here's a quick test of the proposed cases (GCC doesn't have `int128_t` as it appears):

**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=05f9f191777126c744b587af98001714-bff069f172c3f5c3bc4a5e28d7ac9796)**

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/max_element.hpp>
#include <boost/integer.hpp>
#include <limits>

using namespace boost;

namespace best_fit_
{
    // wrappers around Boost Integer http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html#boost_integer.integer.sized
    template <bool is_signed, int bin_digits> struct select_int;

    template <int bin_digits> struct select_int<true, bin_digits> {
        using type = typename boost::int_t<bin_digits + 1>::least;
    };

    template <int bin_digits> struct select_int<false, bin_digits> {
        using type = typename boost::uint_t<bin_digits>::least;
    };

    // query helper
    struct digits {
        template <typename I> using apply = mpl::int_<std::numeric_limits<I>::digits>;
    };
}

template <typename... I>
struct best_common_integral
{
    private:
        using Ints = mpl::vector<I...>;
        using Bits = typename mpl::transform<Ints, best_fit_::digits>::type;

        template <typename J>
            struct is_signed { static constexpr bool value = std::numeric_limits<J>::is_signed; };

        using max  = typename mpl::deref<typename mpl::max_element<Bits>::type>::type;

        // sigh, there is no `mpl::any`, AFAICT
        using sign = typename mpl::fold<
                    Ints, 
                    mpl::bool_<false>, 
                    mpl::if_<is_signed<mpl::_2>, mpl::bool_<true>, mpl::_1>
                >::type;
    public:
        using type = typename best_fit_::select_int<sign::value, max::value>::type;
};

#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using case1 = best_common_integral<long, unsigned long, float, double, int>;
    using case2 = best_common_integral<unsigned int, unsigned long>;
    using case3 = best_common_integral<signed int, signed long>;
    using case4 = best_common_integral<signed int, unsigned int>;
    using case5 = best_common_integral<signed int, unsigned long>;

    //assert(typeid(case1::type) == typeid(double));
    assert(typeid(case2::type) == typeid(unsigned long));
    assert(typeid(case3::type) == typeid(signed long));
    assert(typeid(case4::type) == typeid(signed long));
    //assert(typeid(case5::type) == typeid(int128_t (maybe)));
}
```

Comment: Great solution and use of MPL.

Comment: Please see the comment posted under leonid's answer. It was tough deciding between your answers, because I think yours was more "interesting", but ultimately his was complete and simpler. I will of course keep the +1 for yours as it is also outstanding and an interesting MPL-based approach.

Comment: Sadly this does not work for C++03 due to use of type aliasing.

Comment: @abergmeier C++0x is not a thing. This code is expressly c++11 (the question was tagged [tag:c++11], [tag:variadic-templates] etc.)  There are other answers here that address C++03 (which is what you want)

Answer (score 4):

## Note: somehow I got it stuck in my head that you needed C++03 for this.  This can be simplified for C++11.  This also does NOT pick the smallest size.

There's nothing standard for this to my knowledge, but it can be done:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c6aa42345f91ab51d745d56573b15a04-4f34a5fd633ef9f45cb08f8e23efae0a

First the "thinker" structs.

```
template<bool isfloat, bool negative> struct best_numeric_type 
{typedef long double type;};
template<> struct best_numeric_type<false, true> 
{typedef long long type;};
template<> struct best_numeric_type<false, false> 
{typedef unsigned long long type;};
```

Then the base cases:

```
template<class T> struct best_common_numeric_type1 {
    static const bool isfloat=false;
    static const bool negative=false;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};

template<> struct best_common_numeric_type1<char> {
    static const bool isfloat=false;
    static const bool negative=true;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};//copy-paste for signed char, short, int, long, and long long.

template<> struct best_common_numeric_type1<float> {
    static const bool isfloat=true;
    static const bool negative=false;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};//copy-paste for double and long double.
```

Then the joiners:

```
template<class First, class Second>
struct best_common_numeric_type2 {
    static const bool isfloat = best_common_numeric_type1<First>::isfloat |  best_common_numeric_type1<Second>::isfloat;
    static const bool negative = best_common_numeric_type1<First>::negative |  best_common_numeric_type1<Second>::negative;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};
template<class First, class Second, class Third>
struct best_common_numeric_type3 {
    static const bool isfloat = best_common_numeric_type2<First, Second>::isfloat |  best_common_numeric_type1<Third>::isfloat;
    static const bool negative = best_common_numeric_type2<First, Second>::negative |  best_common_numeric_type1<Third>::negative;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};
template<class First, class Second, class Third, class Fourth>
struct best_common_numeric_type4 {
    static const bool isfloat = best_common_numeric_type3<First, Second, Third>::isfloat |  best_common_numeric_type1<Fourth>::isfloat;
    static const bool negative = best_common_numeric_type3<First, Second, Third>::negative |  best_common_numeric_type1<Fourth>::negative;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};
template<class First, class Second, class Third, class Fourth, class Fifth>
struct best_common_numeric_type5 {
    static const bool isfloat = best_common_numeric_type4<First, Second, Third, Fourth>::isfloat |  best_common_numeric_type1<Fifth>::isfloat;
    static const bool negative = best_common_numeric_type4<First, Second, Third, Fourth>::negative |  best_common_numeric_type1<Fifth>::negative;
    typedef typename best_numeric_type<isfloat, negative>::type type;
};
```

And finally a test:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>       
void printer(long double) {std::cout << "long double\n";}
void printer(unsigned long long) {std::cout << "ull\n";}
void printer(long long) {std::cout << "ll\n";}
void printer(...) {std::cout << "else\n";}
       
int main() {
    printer(best_common_numeric_type5<long, unsigned long, float, double, int>::type());
    printer(best_common_numeric_type2<unsigned int, unsigned long>::type());
    printer(best_common_numeric_type2<signed int, signed long>::type());
    printer(best_common_numeric_type2<signed int, unsigned int>::type());
    printer(best_common_numeric_type2<signed int, unsigned long>::type());
    printer(best_common_numeric_type2<float, char>::type());
}
```

Results:

```
long double
ull
ll
ll
ll
long double
```

Comment: With C++11 you can make `best_common_numeric_type2` and friends a variadic template, which is nicer, and you can use `using` which is merely syntactical in this case.  Other than that C++11 doesn't seem like it'd help this case much.

Comment: This is good, the only problem is that it doesn't meet the first part of the stated criteria (to have the smallest `sizeof` possible). You can see that it is also stated in the question what the resultant `::type` should be for each of the test case examples. This would also clean up nicely with C++11 variadic templates, like you said. Sorry I didn't make that clearer, though I did state in the question "What might be the best way in **C++11** to achieve this?" Again, thanks for your help and interesting discussion! +1

Comment: BTW- check out the solution above from sehe using `boost::mpl` it's quite clean.

Comment: @MikeTusar: Part of the reason it's clean is because it doesn't handle floating point types.  Doing the smallest size is quite hard, and I misunderstood [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283807/determining-the-optimal-common-numeric-type-in-a-template-parameter-pack/18284474?noredirect=1#comment26823226_18283807) as allowing what I did.

Comment: The floating-point cases are trivial because if *any* of the types are an FP type, then `::type` is simply the highest-precision FP type in the pack. The integral cases were the harder ones, and sehe's solution even solved it in a data-model-neutral way by using `boost::int_t<bin_digits + 1>::least` (or `boost::uint_t` depending on signage) which was an added bonus.